# Jenkins Docker on AWS not accessible from Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, port

I am setting up my Jenkins via its Docker Image. I have an AWS ec2 Instance and have successfully setup my Docker and Jenkins according to [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/).

My Open Ports:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-81:~$ netstat -ltpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2376            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::50000                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::2376                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

By Default my Firewall is also Inactive:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-81:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

My jenkins docker is up and running:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-81:~$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                                                                      NAMES
7221bf8dc6c5   myjenkins     "/usr/bin/tini -- /u…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp, :::50000->50000/tcp   jenkins-blueocean
0196b39e8e8d   docker:dind   "dockerd-entrypoint.…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours         2375/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2376->2376/tcp, :::2376->2376/tcp                                        jenkins-docker
```

and the response to curl is also appropriate:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-81:~$ curl 127.0.0.1:8080
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
-->

</body></html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-81:~$
```

and my AWS Inbound rules are also set:
[image: AWS Inbound Rules - Port 8080 is open for all]

**BUT** still when I access my [public url](https://65.1.149.96:8080) - https://65.1.149.96:8080 I am getting Connection Refused. And the same case is with `curl`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-81:~$ curl 65.1.149.96:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 65.1.149.96 port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

Comment: Is this the correct public ip? When you restart EC2 it changes by the way. Also, it's not a good idea to share it on a public forum.

Comment: Yeah, it is the correct Public IP. Yeah, i know it isn't a good idea, but this is just a small personal project and I'll anyways replace it with an Elastic IP down the line. Also I'm kinda desperate, because I have scoured many documentations and forums, and ideally this should be working

Comment: I followed the link and installed on an EC2 and I do not face any issue at all. I did it twice, once as a normal user and once as root. In both cases zero issues! Maybe try using another instance type. I did it on free tier one on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Same, I did it on the t2micro Ubuntu 22.04. Your Jenkins is working from the public IP in the browser?

Comment: Yes! Copy pasted all the commands in the link, a part from installing docker and 0 problems!

Comment: Theres a vote for closure, but Jenkins is used for program develpment